# CREATE TYPE failing with: Incorrect syntax near 'AS'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-types

I have following piece of code:

```
CREATE TYPE FTPLog AS TABLE ( 
   [Date] datetime
       ,[LocalIPAddress] varchar(MAX)
       ,[LocalIPPort] varchar(MAX)
       ,[UserName] varchar(MAX)
       ,[SiteName] varchar(MAX)
       ,[HostName] varchar(MAX)
       ,[RemoteIPAddress] varchar(MAX)
       ,[RemoteIPPort] varchar(MAX)
       ,[Command] varchar(MAX)
       ,[CommandParameters] varchar(MAX)
       ,[BytesSent] int
       ,[BytesReceived] int
   ,[ElapsedMilliseconds] int
       ,[FtpStatus] varchar(MAX)
       ,[FtpSubStatus] varchar(MAX)
       ,[FullPath] varchar(MAX)
       ,[HRStatus] varchar(MAX)
       ,[SessionId] varchar(MAX)
       ,[Information] varchar(MAX)
)GO
```

When I try execute this, I got an error:

```
Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You need to provide the type of sql server and version.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, Server Version 9.0.3042, Managament Studio  10.0.1600.22

Comment: "Server Version 9.0.3042": That's 2005, not 2008. SQL Server 2005 doesn't support this.

Comment: Put your `GO` on the next line down, separate from the `)`.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks :) I had installed two versions of SQL Server (2005 and 2008). Management Studio has connected with wrong one:)

Comment: @hvd Since the problem was resolved in comment, you (or OP) should post is as an answer and close the question. That makes it much easier to find an answer for future people wondering the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hvd said in the comment - this is SQL Server 2005, not 2008. SQL Server 2005 does not support it.